# SSIS foreach loop container

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that use a foreach container to loop through files and import them into a table. I ran into the error that says that there is a partial row at the end of the file and found a solution for it. It worked, but now it is giving that error for only the last file in the loop, and when i run that file by itself, there is no error.

Comment: Could you give some example code and the actual error? It's hard to solve problems without it.

Comment: Its kind of hard to explain but I found a solution to this problem that suggested setting the text nullification for the columns to false. I did that and now I get the warning for just the one file. I am importing the data from the file into a database table. The file has three rows in it and the first row has the column names in it. After it runs, the process says that it processed 1 row and wrote 0.